# Connecting to SQL Server from a different network

Tags: sql-server, sockets, networking, sql-server-2016

I recently set up SQL Server locally and have followed the numerous guidelines on this website and others to connect to it from a different network:

- [Connect to MS SQL Server 2014 from a computer on a different network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870707/connect-to-ms-sql-server-2014-from-a-computer-on-a-different-network)
- [Connect to MS SQL Server 2014 from a computer on a different network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870707/connect-to-ms-sql-server-2014-from-a-computer-on-a-different-network)
- [Firewall rules to allow remote connection to SQL Server in a different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25208032/firewall-rules-to-allow-remote-connection-to-sql-server-in-a-different-domain)
- [How to use SQL server from a different network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906789/how-to-use-sql-server-from-a-different-network)

This is what I have tried so far:

- Ports 1433 and 1434 have been enabled in SQL Server Config Manager
- Based on these suggestions in the links above, I have added inbound rules to my firewall to create exceptions for SQL Server and its associated ports (Ports: 1433 & 1434).

When I try using telnet to connect, I get the following:

> Connection closed by remote host

When I try checking the status of my port from the following website:
http://ping.eu/port-chk/

It indicates that my port is closed (both 1433 & 1434).

When I try connecting from a different machine on the same network, I am able to do so without issue.

I do not understand what other layer of protection exists that is blocking connections to my local version of SQL Server.

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Right click on Server instance and check server properties in that click Connection and see if Allow Remote Connection is enabled

Comment: Thanks for the reply SQL006. Allow remote connections is definitely enabled.

Comment: Do you have a default instance or a named instance?

Comment: At the remote host you will have to grant an access permission to the network machine from where you are trying to connect. It is available in Security option in Object explorer of the host SQL server.

Comment: On the remote machine(s), are the firewall ports opened for 1433, 1434? I assume that you SQL Server is configured to enable TCP/IP in the SQL Server Network Configuration?

Comment: @sepupic I am using a default instance

Comment: @NielsBerglund The remote machine also has SQL installed on it and the ports 1433 and 1434 have been added to the inbound/outbound firewall rules on the machine. Connecting to the remote server is no issue at all. Its just that connections to the local server using the remote server or even telnet do not indicate that a connection has been established. TCP/IP protocols have also been enabled on both servers.